# Auto Fill Mobile Safari Prompt

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, mobile-safari, autofill

Is possible to display a prompt in mobile safari to ask a user to auto-fill a fieldset with their contact info?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Confirm Box](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_popup.asp)

```
if (confirm("Do you want us to auto-fill this form for you?"))
{
    //autofill the form here
}
```